# pythonnet crashes on numpy import

Tags: python, .net, numpy, anaconda, python.net

Environment

- Pythonnet version: 2.3.0
- Python version: Python 3.5 (conda environment)
- Operating System: Windows 10 64bit
- VS 2017

I'm trying to get python.net working and running the example script on their website but it crashes on import of numpy (works on other items). Here is the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (Py.GIL())
    {
        dynamic np = Py.Import("numpy");
        Console.WriteLine(np.cos(np.pi * 2));
<snip>
```

It crashes on numpy import with the following error:

> Python.Runtime.PythonException: 'ImportError : 
>   Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
>   likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
>   If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
>   files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

I've gone through the help pages and, in particular I've followed the instructions in these links:

- https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/463
- https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/259
- https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/645

Note that:

- I had to manually set my `PATH` , `PYTHONPATH` and `PYTHONHOME` variables as well as manually set my `PythonEngine.PythonHome` and `PythonEngine.PythonPath` variables to get it working.
- importing other libraries works
- importing numpy works if I do it from the conda environment

Comment: Don't set pythonpath unless you know what you are doing

Comment: Have a look at this issue: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/490

Comment: OK, thanks @denfromufa. Once I removed the changes I made to the `PATH`, `PYTHONPATH` and `PYTHONHOME` variables then the problem resolved itself.



The links to the pythonnet issues above (463, 259 and 645) suggested changing the environment variables. In fact what you need to do is change the `PythonEngine.PythonHome` and `PythonEngine.PythonPath` variables, and NOT the environment variables.

Comment: To anyone reading this, let me note that I ended up using ProcExp to find out all of the locations that the regular python was touching and therefore I needed to add the following three locations to `PythonEngine.PythonPath: c:\conda_env\lib   c:\conda_env\lib\site-packages and c:\conda_env\dlls